# Apple rejected my app second time

Tags: ios, iphone, backup, data-storage

I have created an app and apple rejected twice to not following ios data storage guidelines, i am surprised because i have already submitted apps without any issue, i am using sqlite to store my data, and i am storing images into document directory and their path into database, what i have did already

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}

-(void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success) {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dbPath]];

        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

-(void)connectWithDB
{
    [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
    [self generateDB];
}
```

and in my booldidfinishWithLaunchingOption function i did

```
[self connectWithDB];
```

i don t know why they have issue,

```
We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.

In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 2.5 MB. To check how much data your app is storing:

Install and launch your app
Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
Check your app's storage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old method.  Use the newer method described in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html)

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: but the old one is for ios 5?

Comment: when i put breakpoint this function never called.. should it put it somewhere else?

Comment: The old one is for 5.0.1.  There is no way to do it for 5.0.0.  This one is for iOS 5.1.  What do you mean "this function is never called"?   You have to call it yourself.